# Javascript - Need a moving vertical carousel to display brands

Tags: javascript

I need something like [this](http://miedlar.com/samples/carousel/sample) to display all brands we sell on our online store. But this one doesn't move unless you "click" next or "previous" and I have specific instructions to have it moving automatically.

Anyone know a good script that satisfies my needs?

I could go about modifying it to automatically move but my javascript skills are somewhat non-existent.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this jQuery Plugin is the most flexible for carousels. Vertical, horizontal, autoscrolling and so on.
http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/

Edit:
Or for Prototype: http://code.google.com/p/prototype-carousel/

Comment: It's jQuery though, its been conflicting massively with Prototype anytime I try to plug it in. This web store is built on Magento which uses Prototype as its JS library. I'll give it a try anyway. Thanks!

Comment: Magento has no problems with jQuery! Just use this plugin from Magento Connect to include it without problems in noConflict-Mode!
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/mxperts/extension/1619/mxperts--jquery-base

But if you want to stick with Prototype this could be the plugin for you: http://code.google.com/p/prototype-carousel/

Comment: Wow! Didn't know about that plugin. That's awesome! Can't thank you enough.